# Google App Engine ThreadSafe

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java project which is hosted through Google App Engine. I mistakenly changed ThreadSafe to false in the appengine-web.xml file, and since have changed it back to true. My application is now acting much slower and is throwing time out errors, which did not occur before I altered the appengine-web.xml file. Could it be the switching of ThreadSafe to false that is causing this behavior? Here is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>my_application_id</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<system-properties>
<property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: After experiencing sustained performance degradation, we tried switching our (python) app back to NON-threadsafe mode and were very surprised to see our performance improved by about 10x. So we've left it off. Our GAE support team wasn't able to explain how this could be. The last time we profiled, we were quite I/O bound to the datastore and in theory should have still been getting a lot of lift from multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to shutdown all existing instances and restarting the app. This will ensure that the latest version is running.

Comment: Then it is not  related to multithreading. What errors do you see in the logs?